# Spark interactive Shell in Spark 1.6.1

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

I just updated from spark 1.3.1 to spark 1.6.1.

In earlier version I was able to launch spark interactive shell in scala using ./bin/spark-shell. In the newer version, I get an error saying "Error: Must specify a primary resource (JAR or Python file)".

I understand that it needs a jar file, but is there a way to just launch the shell and not create these jar files? (for example to play around, and see if a given syntax works?)

Comment: Shell should work... That error sounds like you are trying `spark-submit`

Comment: That is what I thought too. but, the error comes from launching spark-shell.

./spark-shell

Error: Must specify a primary resource (JAR or Python file)
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties

I wonder if I need to change a few things in log4j files?

Comment: Not sure what to say other than try to [download from the site](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html), extract the archive and try again. I haven't had any problems on versions 1.3.1, to 1.6.2, and now 2.0

Comment: Thanks for your response. Still the same issue with 1.6.1 and 1.6.2.

Comment: Have you downloaded the pre built version or the Sources ?